# How do I make cubemaps with Hugin?

Tags: hugin, 360-panorama, pano-projections

How do I generate a cubic projection (AKA cubemap) with Hugin? I have enough images for a 360 view of my scene. I see the [Cubic Projection](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Cubic_Projection.html) in the Hugin documentation but I see no mention of it in the software itself. Preferably, I would like to output each face of the cube in a separate image.

Comment: See: http://vinayhacks.blogspot.com/2010/11/converting-equirectangular-panorama-to.html. Looks like it's more a CLI task with Hugin/Panotools. If you want a GUI, commercial software like [Pano2VR](http://ggnome.com/pano2vr) or the [Flexify](http://www.flamingpear.com/flexify.html) PS plugin are possible solutions.

Comment: Hm, I tried this tutorial using their CLI interface but I'm getting errors: Can't locate auto/Win32/Win32.dll at (eval 1) line 36.
Compilation failed in require at /loader/0x1b468fc/Cwd.pm line 643.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: Well, that tutorial is for Linux users. I think what's going on is that you basically are creating a script/project file that does the six viewpoints as rectilinear remappings with a specified FoV of 90º. If you want to try creating the script directly, [this thread on the panoguide forums](http://www.panoguide.com/forums/qna/8598/) might help you out. Personally, I just ponied up for Pano2VR. :)

Comment: awesome, the panoguide was it. I had to find the documentation for the scripting/program parameters. I'll answer soon with a sample script. Thanks @inkista

Comment: Yeah, the guys on the panoguide board are THE source for messing about with equirectangulars.

Comment: Here is a tutorial using pano tools and hugin. It looks verey simple to implement: http://vinayhacks.blogspot.mx/2010/11/converting-equirectangular-panorama-to.html

Answer (score 1):

[Pano2VR](http://ggnome.com/pano2vr) or [Flexify](http://www.flamingpear.com/flexify.html) are probably your simplest solution, but if you're a scripting geek and have to use Hugin tools, then [scripting  nona commands](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/nona/nona.txt) is the way to go.

Since the panoguides board went down in sea of spam, I go to [the Internet archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20120127220813/http://www.panoguide.com/forums/qna/8598) and post [DorinDXN](http://www.livepanoramas.com)'s answer (with some minor edits) of a Windows .bat file to create six nona_gui scripts and run them to create the six cube face images.

---

> This is the **equi2cubic100.bat** file.
>
> You'll need **nona_gui.exe** from the Hugin distribution.
> In the same folder with nona_gui.exe, place the **pano.tif** that is the
> equirectangular file.
>
> You can change **w1500 h1500** with the desired cube-face dimension in pixels
> **w6000 h3000** with the size of the equirectangular and
> **v100** (100°) for the FoV of the cubic.
>
> Each line starts with @, don't break it into sublines.

```
@echo press any key if pano.tif was produced by PTGui
pause
@echo.
@echo -----------------------------------------------------
@echo Generating Face_0 FRONT
@echo p f0 w1500 h1500 v100 >script.txt
@echo m g1 i2 f0 m0>>script.txt
@echo o w6000 h3000 f4 p0 r0 v360 y0  u10 m0 n"pano.tif">>script.txt
@nona_gui -o cube_0.tif script.txt

@echo.
@echo -----------------------------------------------------
@echo Generating Face_1 RIGHT
@echo p f0 w1500 h1500 v100 >script.txt
@echo m g1 i2 f0 m0>>script.txt
@echo o w6000 h3000 f4 p0 r0 v360 y270  u10 m0 n"pano.tif">>script.txt
@nona_gui -o cube_1.tif script.txt
@echo.

@echo -----------------------------------------------------
@echo Generating Face_2 BACK
@echo p f0 w1500 h1500 v100 >script.txt
@echo m g1 i2 f0 m0>>script.txt
@echo o w6000 h3000 f4 p0 r0 v360 y180  u10 m0 n"pano.tif">>script.txt
@nona_gui -o cube_2.tif script.txt
@echo.

@echo -----------------------------------------------------
@echo Generating Face_3 LEFT
@echo p f0 w1500 h1500 v100 >script.txt
@echo m g1 i2 f0 m0>>script.txt
@echo o w6000 h3000 f4 p0 r0 v360 y90  u10 m0 n"pano.tif">>script.txt
@nona_gui -o cube_3.tif script.txt
@echo.

@echo -----------------------------------------------------
@echo Generating Face_4 UP
@echo p f0 w1500 h1500 v100 >script.txt
@echo m g1 i2 f0 m0>>script.txt
@echo o w6000 h3000 f4 p270 r0 v360 y0  u10 m0 n"pano.tif">>script.txt
@nona_gui -o cube_4.tif script.txt
@echo.

@echo -----------------------------------------------------
@echo Generating Face_5 DOWN
@echo p f0 w1500 h1500 v100 >script.txt
@echo m g1 i2 f0 m0>>script.txt
@echo o w6000 h3000 f4 p90 r0 v360 y0  u10 m0 n"pano.tif">>script.txt
@nona_gui -o cube_5.tif script.txt
@echo.
@del script.txt
```

Comment: If you add the command `@Echo off` to the start of your batch file you won't need to pre-pend each individual `echo` command with an `@`.

Answer (score 1):

The input file (pano.tif above) needs to be a full, spherical panorama, as indicated by 'f4' and the 2:1 aspect ratio.

Each cube face will be a rectilinear panorama, as indicated by 'f0' above. The field of view for the face should probably be 90 degrees, rather than 100 as selected by 'v100' above.

Here is a shell script from MacOS with Hugin installed:

```
#!/bin/sh

# create cube faces
# $1  # path to equirectangular ("full spherical") panorama file (360x180 degrees)
# $2  # cube dimension in pixels
# $3  # cube field of vision (default 90)
# $4  # width of $1 in pixels
# $5  # height of $1 in pixels [should be 0.5 * $4]

# faces are "$1"-{left,right,front,back,up,down}.jpg

p="p f0 w$2 h$2 v$3"       # p-line describes rectilinear panorama on cube face
m="m g1 i2"                # m-line: gamma 1.0 spline36 interpolator
o="o f4 w$4 h$5 v360 r0"   # o-line selects from spherical full panorama

# path to "nona"
nona='/Applications/Hugin/HuginStitchProject.app/Contents/MacOS/nona'

# temporary file for script
tmp="/tmp/$$.oto"
trap 'rm -f $tmp' 0

# remove previous faces, if any
rm -f "$1"-*.jpg

# create scripts and extract the faces
cat > "$tmp" << eof
$p
$m
$o p0 y0 n"$1"
eof
"$nona" -m JPEG -z 95 -o "$1"-front.jpg "$tmp"

cat > "$tmp" << eof
$p
$m
$o p0 y270 n"$1"
eof
"$nona" -m JPEG -z 95 -o "$1"-right.jpg "$tmp"

cat > "$tmp" << eof
$p
$m
$o p0 y180 n"$1"
eof
"$nona" -m JPEG -z 95 -o "$1"-back.jpg "$tmp"

cat > "$tmp" << eof
$p
$m
$o p0 y90 n"$1"
eof
"$nona" -m JPEG -z 95 -o "$1"-left.jpg "$tmp"

cat > "$tmp" << eof
$p
$m
$o p270 y0 n"$1"
eof
"$nona" -m JPEG -z 95 -o "$1"-up.jpg "$tmp"

cat > "$tmp" << eof
$p
$m
$o p90 y0 n"$1"
eof
"$nona" -m JPEG -z 95 -o "$1"-down.jpg "$tmp"
```

[Here](http://schreiner-family.net/talks/drones/full-sphere-to-cubes.workflow.zip) is an archive with an Automator workflow as a graphical user interface for the shell script.